# Slow start up of LM3578

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost

[image]
Hello all,
I have this circuit which will take an input (4x1.5AA (3.5V~6.2V)) and output a boosted voltage of 12V (120mA).
The problem I am facing is that the voltage takes about 10s. to build up from a dead start condition.During this time the battery voltage falls to about 1.8~2V and then recovers to about 0.5V less than open battery voltage,once the o/p voltage has reached 12V.After this the circuit works pretty fine.
I procured a similar circuit from [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/XL6009-DC-DC-Boost-Buck-Converter-Step-Up-Down-Power-Supply-Regulator-Module-/131115775026?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item1e871bf432#shpCntId).The problem is similar with this, though less (maybe about 4 seconds,battery voltage drops to 2~2.2V).
Any suggestions on how to improve this?
TIA.

Comment: The datasheet only guarantees operation from 2V, so if your batteries are sagging below that, you'll either need some sort of soft-start circuit or some extra cells to stay above the minimum operating voltage.

Comment: a) in case you're trying this on a breadboard, then forget the breadboard, and use a real PCB b) try better batteries (you may try a single LiPo battery as a test to see if it makes a difference - it should)

Comment: Will it work correctly without pin 2 connected?

Comment: @Adam : There is a current limiting resistor,so that should prevent excessive draw,even during start up?

Comment: @Laszlo 1)I am doing this on a proper pcb with a ground plane,initially i had used a DIP version on a stripboard,with slightly better results.2)Are LiPo batteries commonly available above 3.7V?I will search.

Comment: @Andyaka The circuit is directly lifted from the datasheet.Pin2 is connected internally to Vref.It is used for shutting down the regulator,externally if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would focus on the coil. How did you select 390 µH, and what is its current rating?

Your symptoms are actually a bit contradictory. The excessive sag in battery voltage suggests that the circuit is drawing far more current than it should during startup, while the slow rise in output voltage suggests that the current is too low for some reason.

If your 390 µH coil is going into saturation, that could explain the excessive current draw, while still being consistent with a slow start-up.

But based on a quick back-of-the-envelope calculation, 390 µH seems to be too high for this application, by about an order of magnitude. Your 1 nF capacitor sets the oscillator frequency at about 80 kHz, which is a 12.5 µs period. The maximum duty cycle of the switch is 90%, or 11.25 µs.

With a minimum input voltage of 3.5 V, an output voltage of 12.0 V and a load current of 120 mA, the coil current is going to need to peak at more than

$$2 \frac{V_{IN}}{V_{OUT}}I_{OUT} = 2 \frac{12.0}{3.5} 120 mA = 823 mA$$

Note that this is already greater than the 750 mA that the chip is specified to handle. You're overloading it, and this is going to cut into your overall efficiency, dropping as much as 0.9V across the switching transistor.

But, in any case, this means that the inductance needs to be less than

$$V_{IN} \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta I} = 3.5 V \frac{11.25 \mu s}{823 mA} = 47.8 \mu H$$

Your 390 µH inductor is acting as a current limiter, severely restricting the amount of current that's available to charge the output capacitor.

Comment: The inductor in this configuration does not limit the output current. It simply lowers the current threshold where the operation changes from DCM to CCM.

Comment: @LaszloValko: Yes, that's true. But if the inductor is saturating, it'll never get there.

Comment: @DaveTweed - So is the 390µH inductor saturating? If not, the sentence starting "If your 390 µH coil is going into saturation ... " is confusing me.

Comment: @DaveTweed: 1)I did the calculations,based on the nomogram in the datasheet.They have a similar example in the ds for 15V@140mA,where the inductor is 330uH. 2)The saturation I of the inductor is 800mA (Bourne SDR1006-391KL).3)Actually 120mA and 3.5V has some factor of safety in it.During normal running after stable 12V is reached, the current drawn from the battery is about 40mA,and when i run it with 3 cells(<4.5V) the battery current is about 70mA.

Comment: As I mentioned the ebay item which I procured has  similar behavior during startup.It uses a 330uH inductor,100uF cap and a XL6009E1 switcher.In both circuits sometimes, rarely it powers up immediately,which is quite perplexing.